# Solr 8.0.0 Delta import Issue

Tags: solr

The delta import is not working. No new records get indexed. posting_id is a unique id for each record.

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            batchSize="-1"
            autoReconnect="true"
            socketTimeout="0"
            connectTimeout="0"
            encoding="UTF-8"
            url="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:3306/news?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
            user="admin"
            password="admin"/>
<document>
<!--<entity name="news10" query="select * from news10"
            deltaQuery="select posting_id from item where last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"> 
</entity>-->
<entity name="news10" pk="posting_id"
  query="SELECT * FROM news10"
  deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM news10
    WHERE posting_id = '${dataimporter.delta.posting_id}'"
  deltaQuery="SELECT posting_id FROM news10
    WHERE last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">
</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580331/solr-delta-import-not-working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110290/solr-delta-import-does-not-working-but-full-import-working-fine